# "Add additional static fbml box" on a Facebook page seems to have vanished

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

On [this tutorial](http://www.hyperarts.com/blog/facebook-static-fbml-troubleshooting-guide-why-code-doesnt-work/) (and all others I could find) they show this image or similar:

[image: additional fbml box]

I remember using this in the past for my page:

http://www.facebook.com/1919reykjavik[image]

On this page I have two static FBML links on the left, and I would like to have a third one. However when I tried going into the edit screen, like the tutorial says, I get this:[image]

i.e.: the `add additional fbml box` button is missing.

Is there a new way to do this that's even more obscure than the old one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, [FBML has been deprecated](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/479).  To add a new tab to your Facebook page you will have to add an existing app or create your own [iframe app](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/462).

> Starting Friday, March 18th, you will
>   no longer be able to create new FBML
>   apps and Pages will no longer be able
>   to add the Static FBML app. While all
>   existing apps on Pages using FBML or
>   the Static FBML app will continue to
>   work, we strongly recommend that these
>   apps transition to iframes as soon as
>   possible.

Comment: thanks, I had a growing suspicion this was the case. Seems I'm getting old.